# Multiple file read in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science

How can we read multiple files in MIPS assembly language? I have a code which read one file but I want to read multiple files through one code? You can download that file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/29gfl8lbr7ldxqt/fileread2.asm)

Comment: Could you post the snippet of code that reads in one file?

Comment: I have added Dropbox link in the question.

Comment: Can't access dropbox from work :(.

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CFYQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipaste.eu%2Fview.php%3Fid%3D2732&ei=kWS4UuTSAcWw7AbejYGQDA&usg=AFQjCNFhKL-l5ofUf02oNl6v5SdBg8PZ8w&sig2=0xBtxLCgjQLqmjvbH4RvPw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE

Comment: Thanks, Can I assume that you would have the list of files in memory in an array/stack? If so, could you not loop through the array and read each file? i.e. get the name from the memory, and then read them?

Comment: I am new to MIPS.I have no clue about arrays and loops in MIPS

Comment: extremely simple instructions. look at `beq`, `bne`, `labels` for looping and `lw`, `sw` for stacks/arrays. It's not too complex at all.

Comment: Any links or a sample code to learn that?

Comment: I've got like 5 links so I'll just put them in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

These are the links I found helpful when I was learning MIPS. Hope they help

[Crash Course](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm)

[Extensive](http://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/education/lectures/TI1/materials/assemblylanguageprogdoc.pdf)

[Simple](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/download/attachments/203522372/L15-LoadStores.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1349711705000)

Relevant Reads:

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/index.html

http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/02au/Lectures/07controlI.pdf

[PowerPoint Presentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=http://www.ann.ece.ufl.edu/courses/eel5764_09fal/slides/assembly_tut.ppt&ei=uGq4UsaPEtbfsASo2IGYAg&usg=AFQjCNEpnZ0KlMgcDiBCmNHZzt0A7LBUwQ&sig2=EY3Ob-Be_bHZOqy2-q5txA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cWc&cad=rja)